# Gradle making deployment jar file

Tags: java, deployment, groovy, jar, gradle

I am trying to create deployment jar file for multi-module project. I am using this code to create it:

```
subprojects.each { subproject -> evaluationDependsOn(subproject.path)}
task allJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: subprojects.assemble) {
    baseName = 'apollo'
    subprojects.each { subproject ->
        from subproject.configurations.archives.buildDependencies.files.collect {
            zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
artifacts {
    archives allJar
}
```

But it build jar with tests which I don't want in my deployment jar is there a way to exclude or maybe I am using wrong code to build a deployment jar.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `exclude` argument should help (as wrote here http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/How-to-exclude-some-classes-from-jar-td3315811.html).

```
subprojects.each { subproject -> evaluationDependsOn(subproject.path)}
task allJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: subprojects.assemble) {
    baseName = 'apollo'
    subprojects.each { subproject ->
        from subproject.configurations.archives.buildDependencies.files.collect {
            zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    exclude('src/test..')
}
artifacts {
    archives allJar
}
```

Read also [gradle Jar API](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) where you will find few `exclude` methods which can be used.

Comment: Try to put `exclude` after `from{}` so it will be used for every subproject.

Comment: I need to exclude one submodule and all test classes. tried this:
http://pastebin.com/RhG2JijN